# Vaadin 14: Resize TextArea after resizing window

Tags: javascript, css, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

with Vaadin 14.1.19 and a Vaadin "My Starter Project"-project I tried to create a multiline TextArea. At first glance it works fine, but when resizing a TextArea, it does not adapt the number of lines.
This is my code:

```
package com.packagename.myapp;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Div;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextArea;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;
@Route(layout = DesktopLayout.class)
@PWA(name = "Project Base for Vaadin Flow with Spring", shortName = "Project Base")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    public MainView(@Autowired MessageBean bean) {
        String loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [....].";
        TextArea readOnlyTA = new TextArea();
        readOnlyTA.setLabel("Read-only");
        readOnlyTA.setWidth("1500px");
        readOnlyTA.setMaxWidth("80vw");
        readOnlyTA.setValue(loremIpsum);
        readOnlyTA.setReadOnly(true);
        add(readOnlyTA);

        TextArea readWriteTA = new TextArea();
        readWriteTA.setLabel("normal");
        readWriteTA.setWidth("1500px");
        readWriteTA.setMaxWidth("80vw");
        readWriteTA.setValue(loremIpsum);
        add(readWriteTA);

        Div readOnlyDiv = new Div();
        readOnlyDiv.setWidth("1500px");
        readOnlyDiv.setMaxWidth("80vw");
        readOnlyDiv.add(loremIpsum);
        add(readOnlyDiv);
    }
}
```

When I open the view with a broad window, it looks like this which is just fine:

[image: Vaadin 14.1.19 TextArea with a lot of text at a wide screen]

When I resize the window, it looks like this which is not fine because only the beginning of the text is readable.
I can't even scroll within the TextAreas.

[image: Vaadin 14.1.19 TextArea with a lot of text at a small screen]

Only the DIV resizes the way I expected.

How can I get Vaadin's TextArea to resize at window resize?

Comment: Vaadin seems to recalculate the height at every value change within the writeable text area: when I type in something, the writeable TextArea just gets the right height, directly as a CSS property in the style-attribute, e.g. "height: 110px".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. I just reported it here https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-text-field/issues/460

As a workaround you could set a window `resize` listener that runs `textArea._updateHeight();` on the client side to trigger the height update. Or you could use a [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) but it still has somewhat limited [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=resizeobserver)

Here's a naive example to add a resize listener workaround in Flow:

```java
textArea.getElement().executeJs(
    "window.addEventListener('resize', function() { $0._updateHeight(); });",
    textArea.getElement());
```

But you should wrap this resize handler in some basic debouncer so that it doesn't run `_updateHeight()` too often while resizing is happening to avoid performance issues.

Alternatively you could do this:

```java
UI.getCurrent().getPage().addBrowserWindowResizeListener(event -> {
    textArea.getElement().executeJs("this._updateHeight();");
});
```

I'm not sure if `addBrowserWindowResizeListener` has some kind of debouncing built in or not but I think this will at least cause server round trips on resize which should probably be avoided if possible.

**Edit:**

Here's a more universal approach by creating a new component that extends Vaadin `TextArea` and uses `ResizeObserver` in supported browsers (with `setInterval` as a fallback for other browsers).

```java
import com.vaadin.flow.component.AttachEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextArea;

public class CustomTextArea extends TextArea {
    private boolean initDone = false;

    @Override
    protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
        super.onAttach(attachEvent);
        if (!initDone) {
            // debounce method borrowed from: https://davidwalsh.name/essential-javascript-functions
            getElement().executeJs(
                    "const debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {" +
                    "  var timeout;" +
                    "  return function() {" +
                    "    var context = this, args = arguments;" +
                    "    var later = function() {" +
                    "      timeout = null;" +
                    "      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);" +
                    "    };" +
                    "    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;" +
                    "    clearTimeout(timeout);" +
                    "    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);" +
                    "    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);" +
                    "  };" +
                    "};" +
                    "const textArea = $0;" +
                    "const updateTextAreaHeight = function() { textArea._updateHeight(); };" +
                    "const debounceTimeout = 50;" +
                    "const intervalTimeout = 500;" +
                    "" +
                    "if (window.ResizeObserver) {" +
                    "  let textAreaDebouncer;" +
                    "  const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(debounce(updateTextAreaHeight, debounceTimeout));" +
                    "  resizeObserver.observe(textArea);" +
                    "} else {" +
                    "  let textAreaWidth = textArea.clientWidth;" +
                    "  window.setInterval(function() {" +
                    "    if (textAreaWidth !== textArea.clientWidth) {" +
                    "      updateTextAreaHeight();" +
                    "      textAreaWidth = textArea.clientWidth;" +
                    "    }" +
                    "  }, intervalTimeout);" +
                    "}", getElement());
            initDone = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then just use this `CustomTextArea` instead of `TextArea` and it should work.

Comment: Hi Haprog, a WindowResizeListener seems to be just a part of the universal solution. A resize of an input field / TextArea also can happen when the field is placed within a Split Layout: https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-split-layout

Comment: That is true. ResizeObserver on the component would be an optimal solution, but until that has wider browser support you probably need to use different solutions based on context depending on which events can trigger resizing of the component width.

Window resize is probably the most common case which is easy to listen on, but if the component width may change without the window being resized then you need another trigger based on your context.

Comment: With `SplitLayout` you can use `addSplitterDragendListener()` or the related `splitter-dragend` event on the client side splitter element.

Comment: As a universal solution you might be able to use some ResizeObserver polyfill on the client side or fall back to polling the component width on some interval (to check if the width has changed) on browsers that don't support ResizeObserver.

Comment: @S.Doe I edited my answer and added an example of how to extend TextArea so that you can easily use a custom version (with built in fix/workaround) anywhere.

Comment: Successfully testet with Chromium 80.0.3987.132 and Firefox 74.0. With window resize and with moving the slitter in a SplitLayout. Great. Thank you! :-)